# Kendo UI (listView) - Add new item to ul

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-listview

I am using Kendo UI ListView.

I want to add new `<li>` item to existing `<ul>` on clicking of `+ add` link. But it has to open **Kendo Popup** with editable **textfield** for "Item Text", and **Select box** for Item Options with options as `Option 01, Option 02....` etc..

**Please help as I am new to jQuery and Kendo :(**

> **[Online Demo](http://dojo.telerik.com/UFEna)**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>Kendo UI Snippet</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2015.3.1111/styles/kendo.common.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2015.3.1111/styles/kendo.rtl.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2015.3.1111/styles/kendo.silver.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2015.3.1111/styles/kendo.mobile.all.min.css"/>

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2015.3.1111/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  
<a href="#" id="addNewItem">+ Add</a>
  
<ul id ="listView"></ul>
  
<script>
var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
  data: [ { itemText: "Default item 1", itemOption: "Option 01" }, { itemText: "Default item 2", itemOption: "Option 02" }]
});
$("#listView").kendoListView({
     dataSource: dataSource,
     template: "<li>#:itemText# : #:itemOption#</li>",
 });
dataSource.read();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

One solution can be something like this: [Dojo example](http://dojo.telerik.com/UFEna/4)

Comment: **@Ademar**... Thanks, this is more than enough... **I am Accepting your answer and Upvoting**... Keep up the good work...